# Changing value of object field after validation

Tags: java

I have a Java object `User` with following fields :

```
public class User {
      private String firstName;
      private String desc;
      private String lastName;
      private String profile;
      ... }
```

On some of the String fields I need to do validation with my own validation constraint and if that validation constraint fails , I want to change the value of that corresponding field to some default value.

I am saving this object in my database through hibernate.

For validation I have written my own constraint validator (like the one shown in this example
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-validator)

I am able to validate these fields with my custom validator  but I don't know how to change the value of corresponding field to default value in case this validation fails.

Comment: How to change the value . Currently method is :
isValid(final String value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) . Here "value" is my actual field value . If I change this value it wont change the actual field value.

Comment: Yes you're right - And it's anyway forbidden: ["isValid() (...) The state of value must not be altered."](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/2.0/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class UserValidator {
    public User validate(User user) {
        // check user fields, make sure they are valid
        // if they are, return the same user
        // if not, create another user object, with the required changes, and return that
    }
}

session.save(new UserValidator().validate(user));
```

Comment: It is always not the default value , in some cases I need to change the value by appending some other characters to it.

Comment: it is best to create your own Validator then, edited my answer

Comment: Seems this is the best possible way right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes to the fields of the object and call session.update(object)